# Gaps between HTML section elements

Tags: css, html, sections

I'm not sure why this is happening, but for some reason there are gaps between some `<section>` element on a layout that I am working on.

Currently I have 3 separate sections:

```
<section class="top">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Top Section</h2>
    </div>
 </section>
 <section class="middle">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>Middle Section</h2>
     </div>
  </section>
  <section class="lower">
     <div class="wrapper">
       <h2>Lower section</h2>
     </div>
  </section>
```

CSS (for the `.wrapper`) - have no other CSS for the `section`:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And then this is the result:

[image]

I don't have any `ul`'s or any other markup in there nor when I inspect each section is there any margin or padding showing. I am using Bootstrap, but I wouldn't think that would mess with the sections.

**HOWEVER**...if I add:

```
* {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

That will fix it and the gaps are gone.

So with that being said, do I *need* to have `overflow: auto` in my CSS to "nuke" out the gaps with the sections elements? Will that cause issues down the line with other elements that I add into each sections? Seems strange that I would need to append each `section` element to compensate for some wonky behavior with the browser or Bootstrap? I've never really seen this before either when using `section` elements this way, so I'm inclined to believe that it might be Bootstrap messing with things.

Comment: Can you post your page's `head` section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h2` has a browser-specified base style for `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`. Set them to `0` to fix your issue.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="top">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Top Section</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="middle">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Middle Section</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="lower">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Lower section</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Well, hell. Yep, that was it. Ugh...you would _think_ that would be taken out by Normalize/Reset...but I guess not. Thanks!